# Wolfram Workbench - how to rename local variables

Tags: workbench, refactoring

I'm refactoring some old code. I used really short names for local variables, which I'm coming to regret. **Is there an easy way to rename local variables in scope using Wolfram workbench?**

Here is an example

How could I change `d` inside `Test`, but not in the `Print` statement?

```
Test[d_]:=d+1;
(*Some other code*)
Print[d];
```

Or the same for `l` inside `Module`?

```
Test1[x_]:=Module[{l},l=x+1];
(*Some other code*)
Print[l];
```

There is a Ctrl+1 [QuickFix](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/quickfixes/variables.html) rename variable, which I discovered while researching this question, but it seems to work only on the whole file...

Using WB 2.0 (anybody even still uses WB 1.1?)

Comment: @b.gatessucks Because the the `d` in test and the `d` in some other module have different functions. This is a simplified example. In real life I have several "functions", which all have the variable `data`. But in each function I would like to change `data` to some specific, more meaningful, name.

Comment: I would suggest a two stage procedure: first use the refactoring functionality to replace the symbol with one with a longer, unique name for the whole file. Then select each of the Modules and use the standard eclipse search and replace functionality to (string-)replace the unique longer symbol name with the desired new name which will let you act on the selected lines only...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Well, what I'm doing at the moment is copying each module to a temp `.m` file, do the replacements there and copy back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this works in all cases: If you highlight a region with the mouse and press Ctrl+F for the "find and replace", this will only search for words inside the highlighted area. This also works for the replace then. I tried it with a small example and it worked.

Comment: Yes, this works in all cases (you have to make sure that scope is set to `selected lines`). Also `whole word` and perhaps `match case` should be set under the options in the find/replace dialog. Then it mimics the rename quite well.

Comment: Perfect. I wonder if there is some other possibility using "Refactor". I tried to use the Refactor > Pattern Replace on a code selection, but it applies to the whole code instead of only the selection...

Comment: Well, I guess I'll accept the `Ctrl+F` as the best that can be done.